# Check English grammar

Tags: c#, nlp, grammar

I am looking for a simple C# library that does the following: Takes a string representing a single sentence, and returns a boolean saying if it's grammatically correct.

I have not been able to find a single, self-contained library that does this after extensive searching.

Comment: This is not a trivial task and there are a limited number of NLP libraries for .NET - One suggestion might be to take advantage of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace and see if you can extract some of the grammar-checking abilities in MS Word.

Comment: If this was a trivial task, we would see these algorithms used all over language translators...

Comment: Did you check OpenNLP / SharpNLP? Here is the [SharpNLP website](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/discussions/263620) and an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12109/Statistical-parsing-of-English-sentences) on Code Project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have MS Word installed you can include a reference to the COM library "Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library" in your project. (I think there may also be a .NET interop library, but I haven't tested it).

Then in your code you can simply invoke:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application myWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

...

return myWord.CheckGrammar("Your string here");
```

And that should do it.